# How to get UI Bootstrap Tabs to send an event when tab is changed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, event-handling, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<uib-tabset type="tabs">
  <uib-tab heading="Event Workflow Activities">
    <div ng-include src="'webapp/event/EventWorkflowActivities.tpl.html'"></div>        
  </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

I am using UI Bootstrap Tabs like above, is there any way to get broadcast an event when you switch between tabs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the select attribute on the tab to execute a function in your controller that does the broadcast.  Like this:

```
<uib-tabset type="tabs">
    <uib-tab heading="Event Workflow Activities" select="tabSelected()">
            <div ng-include src="'webapp/event/EventWorkflowActivities.tpl.html'"></div>        
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Add the select attribute like above that points to a function in your controller.  I named this one tabSelected();

Now in your controller create the function:

```
$scope.tabSelected = function () {
    //Broadcast or emit your event here.

    // firing an event upwards
    $scope.$emit('yourEvent', 'data');

    // firing an event downwards
    $scope.$broadcast('yourEvent', {
      someProp: 'value'
    });
};
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) for more information.

Comment: for those using the controller as syntax and a repeater this would look like select="myCtrl.tabSelected(tab.someProperty)"